# Chance on pairs when picking 'Sinterklaas tickets'

Tags: combinatorics

In the Netherlands, we have a tradition called [Sinterklaas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas). He's a saint, lives in Spain, comes with a steamboat to the Netherlands somewhere in the end of November, and on the 5th of December he comes to bring presents to the children. Because it's his birthday.

Once people get older they start to mimic Sinterklaas: in a small group they pick tickets with their own names on it, a couple of weeks before. You have to prepare a present, poem or surprise craftwork-thing for this person. Of course you can't pick yourself: if someone picks himself, everyone picks a new ticket.

We played this in a group of 22, and it turned out that there was a pair: person A got person B and vice versa. I then wanted to calculate the chances on that, and then in general for $n$ persons.

I started by checking how many possible ticket distributions there are. If I'm not mistaken, there are $D_n$ possible ticket distributions, where $D_n$ is the number of derangements of an $n$-elements set.

Then, say we call one of the persons who's in the pair the first person. He has $n-1$ possibilities for his ticket (not himself). Then, we call the other person from the pair, the second person. He has $1$ possibility for his ticket (the first person). For the rest of the persons we have $D_{n-2}$ possibilities, as we don't really care about them.

Then, the whole probability would be:

$$\frac{(n-1)\cdot D_{n-2}}{D_{n}} = (n-1)\cdot\frac{(n-2)!}{n!}\cdot\frac{1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}{1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}{1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}$$

Calculating this for $n=22$ [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F22*%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B20%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5Ei%7D%7Bi%21%7D%7D%7B1-%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B22%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5Ei%7D%7Bi%21%7D%7D) approximately $0.045$.

Since I'm more familiar with programming than with math, I then wrote a [program](http://pastebin.com/inrwwDqU) that calculates 10,000 random derangements of a 22-elements set, and then checks for how many there's a pair. The answer is always around 7800, so it seems my math is incorrect. I don't see where though. Do you?

Comment: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038219/secret-santa-perfect-loop-problem/1038331#1038331) I calculated the chance that you have a full cycle given a derangement.  You seem to b allowing any cycle larger than $2$

Comment: @RossMillikan I allow any cycle larger than 2, but there has to be a cycle of length 2.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to calculate the probability that a random derangement of $n$ contains _at least_ one $2$-cycle?

Comment: In fact the number of derangements $D_n$ is the closest natural to $\frac {n!}e$, so you are very close to $\frac 1n$ in your calculation.  The extra two terms in the sum contribute almost nothing.

Comment: @MarkvanLeeuwen exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your logic.  If you imagine lining the people up to pick the names, you are requiring that the first person be part of the pair.  In fact, there are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ possible pairs, while you only accounted $n-1$.  If you just make this change, you will double count the cases were there are two pairs, triple count the cases where there are three, etc.  You need the inclusion-exclusion principle to sort this out.

One way to calculate the number of derangements without a pair is to form all the partitions of $n$ into parts at least $3$.  This will be the cycle structure of the derangement.  So, for example, $10=10,7+3,6+4,5+5,4+3+3$.  Each cycle of size $m$ can be formed in $(m-1)!$ ways, so the number of derangements  without a pair for $10$ is $9!+{10 \choose 3}6!2!+{10 \choose 4}5!3!+\frac 12{10 \choose 5}4!^2+\frac 12{10 \choose 4}{6 \choose 3}3!2!2!=809856$  The binomial coefficients choose the elements that go in that cycle.  The leading $\frac 12$ reflects that when you have two cycles of the same size, we have double counted by making each one first.  The values are given in [OEIS A038205](http://oeis.org/A038205).  It states that these numbers are about $n!e^{-3/2}$, so as a fraction of derangements it would be about $e^{-1/2} \approx 0.60653$.  For $n=22,$ they get $250798462399300784640$, which is about [0.60653 of the derangements per Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=250798462399300784640*e%2F22%21)  The chance of having at least one $2-$cycle is then about $1-0.60653=.39347$

Comment: I was hoping to get around that. Thanks anyway, of course!

Comment: @CamilStaps Interesting that this is about half of the experimental value.  Suggests that perhaps you are double-counting somewhere in your code?

Comment: @ErickWong sorry, I didn't see this answer was updated, and thought you were comparing my calculation and my experiment. You're probably right, I will check later tonight (I'm now doing Sinterklaas)

Comment: @ErickWong I don't see the error so quickly. I will look at it again tonight. But here's the code, for reference: http://pastebin.com/inrwwDqU (I will also include it in my question)

Comment: In the limit of large $n$, the number of 2-cycles of a permutation on $n$ elements is Poisson-distributed with mean $1/2$.  (For $k$-cycles, it's $1/k$.)   In particular, it's zero with probability $e^{-1/2}$.  Restricting to derangements doesn't change this too much.  This is a high-level explanation for the asymptotic result quoted in OEIS.

Comment: @CamilStaps Actually, rather than double-counting, most likely your is_derangement is always returning true.  The incidence of permutations having cycles of length 1 or 2 in the space of all permutations is $1-e^{-3/2} \approx 0.7769$ which would explain your findings.

Comment: @ErickWong hm, that's interesting, although I did test that function and it does not _always_ return true, maybe too often. Ah well, anyway...